# asp.net webservice object manipulation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, anonymous-types

Possibly not specific to webservices, but...

I have a webmethod that returns:

```
List<Tadpole> myList = getList();

return new { data = myList , count = 5 };
```

It returns this as JSON.

my code checks `myList[x].fishsticks` which isn't actually part of the `Tadpole` class (so it errors). I am wondering, can I add a `fishsticks` attribute to `myList` somehow to avoid the error, so it gets included when I return the data?

Is there perhaps another elegant solution for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you'll have to add a `fishsticks` property to `Tadpole`.

```
public class Tadpole
{
    //....
    public int Fishsticks { get; set; } 
}
```

Also, why are you adding a `.Count` property to your JSON type? Wouldn't it make more sense to just `.data.Count`, or just return the list and skip the wrapper entirely?

I haven't checked what properties of `List<>` get serialized lately, so it's possible that it's not included, but even if that's the case it would make more sense to do this:

```
List<Tadpole> myList = getList();

return new { data = myList , count = myList.Count };
```

Or, create a descendant class that overrides .Count and adds a serialization attribute.

**Edit**

If I remember correctly, anonymous/dynamic types are internally implemented as dictionaries, while classes are, well, not. (BTW, anonymous types and dynamic objects bring a host of performance and maintenance issues along with them.)

If you don't want to modify Tadpole for some reason, you could always create a descendant class:

```
public class HungryTadpole : TadPole
{
    public int FishSticks { get; set; } 
}
```

Strong typing is your friend and will save you *many* headaches down the road.

Comment: Ah cool, wasn't sure if there was some nifty anonymous type method of adding the attribute. I'll do that. As for count, it actually returns the total number of items available, whereas the data is just returning the top 10 results or whatever was requested (so it knows how many pages to put on the paging control)

Comment: @SLC okay, I can understand that. See update. (You might consider giving them more meaningful names, like TotalRecordsAvailable and Top10Records or some such. Have pity on those that will wind up maintaining this when you're gone!)